Error: Segment names may not start with erroneous periods ('..nextauth'). - NextJS
I am writing an app in NextJS using Typescript, and I'm encountering this error:
Error: Segment names may not start with erroneous periods ('..nextauth').
These are the full logs of when I run npm run dev:
> event-management@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.3
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env

 ✓ Starting...
Error: Segment names may not start with erroneous periods ('..nextauth').
    at UrlNode._insert (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:83:23)
    at UrlNode._insert (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:142:40)
    at UrlNode._insert (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:142:40)
    at UrlNode.insert (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:13:14)
    at C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:165:46
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getSortedRoutes (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\sorted-routes.js:165:21)
    at Watchpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\n_mac\Desktop\Coding\react\event management\event-management\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:558:65)

By the looks of it, the error's originating from Next itself, so I have no idea what's happening. Any help will be much appreciated!

I presume you've made the same typo as me and used two periods instead of three periods when creating a Dynamic Route in NextJS.
I'd therefore recommend to rename the [[..nextauth]] folder to [[...nextauth]] .
Let me know if that helped!
David
